# JSONデータをListFragmentに渡す方法を教えていただけませんか？

Tags: android, json, android-listfragment

JSONデータをListFragmentに渡す方法を教えていただけませんか？

詳細：
JSONArrayで習得したJSONデータをLogで各項目ごとに表示されるまでは確認できております。
このデータをListFragmentでカスタムリスト表示（画像とタイトル、選択したらHPに移動）させたいのですが、具体的な方法にたどり着けておりません。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

ちなみに、ListFragmentプログラムは下記を参考にしております。
http://qiita.com/mackiso/items/09c2bfc99edd5f66f42f

動作確認をするため、JSONデータの代わりにListFragmentのonStart()にを記載、ボタンが押されることでリスト項目が追加され、項目を選択するとHPに移動します。
これらの動作には問題がないことを確認しています。
JSONで得られる３要素（画像、タイトル、コメント）を下記のadapter.add()に渡すことができれば、動作できると考えております。

以下にListFragmentの構文を追記します。

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static ItemListAdapter adapter;
　    
    public ItemListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set adapter
        adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        this.getView().findViewById(R.id.one).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               　
　　　　　　    　//ここでボタンを押すと下記の内容がリストに追加されていきます。
　　　　　　　    adapter.add("icon","google","https://www.google.co.jp/");

            }
        });
    }
```

以下は、JSONデータの構造です。

```
[
{"title":"タイトル01","content":"http:XXX0","image":"http:YYY0"}
,
{"title":"タイトル02","content":"http:XXX1","image":"http:YYY1"}
,
{"title":"タイトル03","content":"http:XXX3","image":"http:YYY3"}
,
{"title":"タイトル04","content":"http:XXX4","image":"http:YYY4"}
,
{"title":"タイトル05","content":"http:XXX5","image":"http:YYY5"}
,
{"title":"タイトル06","content":"http:XXX6","image":"http:YYY6"}
,
{"title":"タイトル07","content":"http:XXX7","image":"http:YYY7"}
]
```

試したことは、
１　上記addをJSON解析のfor文に入れ、解析動作とともに追加する。
２　SharedPreferencesでJSONデータを記憶→ListFragmentで読み出し。
３　fragment.setArguments(bundle);等を使用したFragmentに値を渡す方法。

その他、色々試しているのですが、うまく行っておりません。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 情報が断片的すぎるので、`ListFragment`に設定している`Adapter`の組み立て部分を記述していただけないでしょうか？(`setListAdapter()`を呼ぶとこまで)

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘頂いた部分を追加させていただきました。
アドバイスをいただけたら幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。さらにリクエストで申し訳ないですが、JSONデータの構造も載せていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: お世話になります。
　JSONデータの構造を追加させていただきました。
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonArrayをどこから`ListFragment`に渡すのかわからないのですがActivityから`ListFragment`の載っているActivityへ渡すならば､`Bundle`で自作したオブジェクトを渡す場合はそのオブジェクトに`Parcelable`を実装すればできると思います｡  また､`Application`クラスを実装したクラスを作成し､データを一時的にそのクラスに保存することもできると思います｡ 
親Activityからそこに実装されたの`ListFragment`へのデータ渡しであれば､`ListFragment`に作成したメソッドを親Activityからデータ取得終了後に呼び出して､その引数でJsonArrayを渡す方法があります｡ また､前者と同様に`Application`クラスを用いることもできると思います｡

また､`SharedPreference`は永続的に保存したいデータを保持する目的に使うべきなのでこのような用途に使うべきではありません｡

しかし､ActivityからActivityへそのような大きなデータを渡すことはActivity同士の結合が強くなってしまうのであまりオススメできないように思います｡
できるのであれば､`ListFragment`内でデータを取得するべきだと思います｡

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
ListFragmentからの呼び出しなど考えが至らなかったこと、勉強になりました。
現在、時間が取れず検証に時間がかかりますが、fkmさんの方法も含めて試してみます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 結果をご報告します。
　zousan様とfkm様のアドバイスで無事、動作いたしました。
　ご指摘を参考にListFragmentでの処理を行いました。
　お二人のアドバイスに、本当に感謝しております。
　ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`ItemListAdapter`の`add()`の仕様とJSONデータの仕様があっているかはやや疑問ではありますが、ボタンを押した時にこんな感じの処理をしてみましょう。

```
@Override    
public void onClick(View v) {
    JSONArray array = loadData(); // なんらかの方法でJSONデータをとってくる
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; ++i) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String title = obj.optString("title", "");
        String content = obj.optString("content", "");
        String image = obj.optString("image", "");
        adapter.add(image, title, content);
    }
    // これ呼ばないと実際にListViewに反映されない               　
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: お世話になっております。
現在、時間が取れず検証に時間がかかりますが、zousanさんのアドバイスも合わせて試して見たいと思います。（特に、「なんらかの方法でJSONデータをとってくる」を何パターンか重点的やってみます）
質問文の細かい修正の点も合わせてお世話になりました。
ありがとうございました。